# fade in and fade out animation on the div using Angular.js and CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I am working on custom notifications.
I would like to apply fade in and fade out animation to the div.
I have a set time out method which triggers every 30 seconds, which closes the div. also there is a cross button which closes the div. when we close it should fade out.

tm is the list that is dynamically generated. When ever I have something in the list I get a notification which should fade in. right now I got every thing working except the animation.

```
<div ng-repeat="t in tm" class="alert alert-danger">
        <figure><img class="alert-close close"
                     ng-click="closeToastMessage(toast._id)"
                     src="/img/Notification/RCWeb6_6NTF_IMG_ExitMinorNotification.svg" alt="&times;"/></figure>
            <p class="alert-header">[[t.message.title]]</p>
            <p class="alert-message">[[t.message.errorMessage]]</p>

    </div
```

Comment: are you using `fadeOut()` in  `closeToastMessage` function ?

Comment: I am not using fadeout; app is built on meteor; $scope.closeToastMessage = function (id) {
            ToastMessages.remove({_id: id});
        } ...This removes the id from mongo. there by updating the angular list.

Comment: if possible post your `closeToastMessage()` logic to figure whats missing

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$scope.closeToastMessage = function (id) { 
    $('#'+id).fadeOut(500, function() {
        ToastMessages.remove({_id: id}); 
    });
}
```

Comment: Why should op try this? How will it answer the question?